# Solve for a matrix if I have a desired first eigenvalue with R?

Tags: r, linear-algebra, solver, eigenvalue

Here is a simplified version of my problem. Suppose I have the following matrix:

```
[0  4x
.6   0]
```

I want to solve for x given that I want my first (biggest) eigenvalue to be equal to 1. Is there an easy way to solve this in R?

Comment: I'm looking for a general way to solve. The matrix I'm truly interested in is size 6x6 and I may want to expand to even larger matrices. I made the example in my question simple because I didn't think it was necessary to overcomplicate the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
f <- function(x){
    m <- matrix(c(0, 4*x, .6, 0), 2, 2, byrow=TRUE)
    Re(eigen(m)$values[1]) - 1
}
uniroot(f, c(-1, 1))$root
```